# Oracle Query For Getting Particular Column when user enters multiple inputs

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I have a situation like this I have a table say A.

```
    ID sid RE
    -- --- --
     1 123 BE
     2 123 BE
     2 234 FR
     3 123 BE
     3 156 LU
     3 184 FR
```

if the user gives `sid = 123 and RE = 'BE'` as input i need to give only id as 1. if the user gives `sid = 123 and RE = 'BE' and sid 234` and RE FR I need to give only 2.

i have constructed an oracle query like this

```
    select   min(id)as id, sid, re
    from     a
    where    sid = 123 and re = 'be'
    group by sid, re
    ;
```

For only one SID=123 and RE=BE as input it is working fine. But then if user passes 123 BE,234 FR how to pass this to the above query and get only 2 as output?

I want to convert this query to JPQL and pass the list of sid and re.That is my intention

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a particular value in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341822/getting-a-particular-value-in-oracle)

Comment: DUPLICATE of the same OP's question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341822/getting-a-particular-value-in-oracle   I flagged it as such. I asked the OP to clarify his question (it is not clear how a user passes in one sid and re or two sid and re pairs); instead he posted the question again.

Comment: When Gordon doesn't answer, you know something is up.  I predict either a duplicate mark, or maybe a downvote coming my way.

Comment: But you did not answer this properly what it want to send list of sid and re

Comment: @mathguy i want to convert this query to jpql that sid and re is a list

Comment: So, what is your query supposed to produce? The HIGHEST (greatest) id of all the pairs (sid, re) from table A that match the list? In your query you used MIN, but in the example you said you want 2 to be the answer. Also, how is the list given - assume to Oracle it looks like a table B, with two columns sid and re? And - is it possible the list will also have pairs that are not in table A?

Comment: no the query should produce the exact id of the input passed ie for 123 BE and 234 FR it should produce 2 this 123 BE and 234 FR i will pass a list in java

Comment: If you "want to convert this to JPQL" then post the ENTITY CLASSES!!! You cannot quote JPQL without such basic info since that query then needs classes/fields

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(t.ID)
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, sid, RE
    FROM a
    WHERE (sid = 123 AND RE = 'BE') OR (sid = 234 AND RE = 'FR')
) t
```

Note: I think you intended to `OR` together your criteria in the `WHERE` clause, since a record cannot simultaneously have two different `sid` values.

Comment: Your skills at understanding what the OP wanted are clearly much better than mine.  ;-)

Comment: @mathguy The Java portion of his question is non-trivial, but then again is probably too broad for an answer because it would require a lot of code when the OP has given none.